# I have some trouble in using the curve_fit function

Tags: python-3.x

I want to fit a scatter plot with the curve_fit function. But although I wrote the codes as the tutorial said, it just didn't work.Could someone please help me check the code?

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

rcParams['axes.unicode_minus']=False
myfont = FontProperties(fname='/Library/Fonts/Songti.ttc',size=15)

ydata=[78,78,77.9,74,8,70.1,65.8,58.2,40,5.0,14.0,30,60,69,74,74.2,78,78]
xdata = [257.6695,257.6695,257.6695,307.7231,316.009,309.4141,310.936,312.627,314.4871,316.3472,    317.0236,317.7,319.391,321.082,322.9421,    324.464,    341.7122,426.7695]
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'*')
plt.xlabel('磁感应强度B(mT)',fontproperties=myfont)
plt.ylabel('检波电流(μA)', fontproperties=myfont)


def func(x,amp,cen,wid):
    return amp*np.exp(-(x-cen)**2/wid)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata)
print(popt)
amp = popt[0]
cen = popt[1]
wid = popt[2]
residuals = ydata-func(xdata,amp,cen,wid)
fres = sum(residuals**2)
print(fres)

xaxis = np.linspace(250,450,100)
curve_y = func(xaxis,amp,cen,wid)
plt.plot(xaxis,curve_y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is there a particular error you are getting? If you aren't getting an error then what is the output you expect? See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

With `maplotlib.pyplot`, you need to explicitly state that you want to “show” the plot in order to have it displayed.

`plt.plot(x, y)` will create the barebones of the graph, but there are still many changes one could make: adding additional figures or subplots, adding additional data sets to the plot for comparison or changing colours!

Until you explicitly say “show me the plot at this point in the code”, then nothing will happen. Try adding the following to the end of your code:

```
plt.show()
```